# How to select multiple columns in excel for cut and paste

Tags: microsoft-excel, cut-and-paste

As shown in the following screenshot I have clicked across the headers of three columns:

[image]

But - as you might have *also* noticed - the first row entry on the third column seems to also in some fashion have been *specially* selected.  That is causing an issue when the columns are "cut":

[image]

Note: when selecting a *single* column this issue does not arise: the *specially selected* cell does not show up - and the entire column may be cut and paste as expected.

So then - how to select all columns as a single selection that can be manipulated together  - as for example *cut and paste* ?

I am on excel 15.39 on macos.

Comment: What version of Excel on what platform?

Comment: @teylyn yea- that's starting to look important  - excel 15 on macos . have updated the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The "Special selection" seems be the currently selected cell. It should not affect copy and paste possibilities.

What would affect the possibilities to copy is if you have Hidden rows.

Click the square just left of the "A"-column (above "1"-row) to select all cells. The right click above any row label and select "Unhide" in the pop-up menu.

Comment: I have not done any hiding of columns.  When selecting a single column this issue does not arise. I will update the OP.

Comment: I assume you meant "hiding of rows" (why not check anyway, mistakes do happen?).

Comment: There are no hidden rows.

Comment: Something to try: Select a cell OUTSIDE the columns you wish to copy, then select the columns, copy.

Comment: As mentioned in the update to the OP  - cut/paste of a single one of the mentioned columns does work.

Comment: Last idéa: Select one column at a time, copy. Does the dialog appear for only one column? Is there an active editing lock on the worksheet?